# Is WiFi 5Ghz band faster than 2.4Ghz band on the same network?

Tags: wireless-router, desktop, bandwidth, wireless-adapter, dual-band

I have just purchased a dual band wireless router for my home network. I enable both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz bands with different SSIDs. My desktop's wireless adapter can only connect to the 2.4Ghz band. I'm considering buying a new dual band adapter in order to use the 5Ghz band, but i want to know if it will help the network speed for my desktop?

Comment: Have you done any [research](http://www.speedguide.net/faq/is-5ghz-wireless-better-than-24ghz-340)?

Comment: [Wireless Networking Speed: Ideals and Experiences](http://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/2168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why someone downvoted this as this is a questions forum, but the difference between the 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands would be that:

- 2.4GHz covers a larger distance and travels well through walls, but has slightly reduced data transfer bandwidth;
- 5GHz covers a smaller distance and travels poorly through walls, but has a slightly higher data transfer bandwidth.

I recommend testing them on your own to properly learn the differences and see for yourself, but that is the main difference. Use the 2.4GHz band if you'll be in another room far away from the router; use the 5GHz band if you'll be in the same open area as the router for a slight increase in data transfer from the router to your computer. I use the 2.4GHz band myself, btw.

Comment: I downvoted the question due to the apparent lack of research the author performed before asking this question.

Comment: I see. I can understand that, even I've had simple questions like that in the past, but I've gone to Google for the answers.

Comment: @Dooley_labs Sorry, I thought my comment would be enough to make you realize you kept writing 2.5GHz when it's really the 2.4GHz band. No 802.11/Wi-Fi channel touches any part of the 2.500–2.599GHz band.

Comment: @spiff xD I can't believe I typed that. I'm so sorry. It's fixed.